# How to write dictionary with strings to Excel in python?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, type-conversion, output

I have a dictionary with four keys and a single value called objvalcom. The keys are called k, i, g and t.

```
objvalcom = 
('1', '78', 1, 1): 0.10425768417200648,
 ('1', '78', 1, 2): 0.10425768417200648,
 ('1', '78', 1, 3): 0.04293409610027326,
 ('1', '78', 1, 4): 0.04293409610027326,
 ('1', '78', 1, 5): 0.023951084622771148,
 ('1', '78', 1, 6): 0.023951084622771148,
 ('1', '78', 1, 7): 0.007679931927769335,
 ('1', '78', 1, 8): 0.007679931927769335,
 ('1', '78', 1, 9): 0.007679931927769335,
 ('1', '78', 1, 10): 0.007679931927769335,
 ('1', '78', 1, 11): 0.007679931927769335,
 ('1', '78', 1, 12): 0.007679931927769335 . . . }
```

I'd like to write this to an Excel file so that each of the keys are in their own column and the value is in a fifth column. Also, if the first two keys could be converted from strings to ints that would make the excel file a lot more useful, if there's a way to do that after the dictionary has already been created.

Edit:
This is how the dictionary is created, in case that matters to define the field names.

```
objvalcom = {} # objective value by commodity
for k, i,g in dnode:
        for t in timep:
                objvalcom [k, i, g,t] = sum(mydict_weightn[(k, i,g)] * (mydict_phite[(k, i,g)] - solutiondnode[k, i,g, t]) for k, i,g in dnode.select('*', '*', g )) / sum(
                    mydict_weightn[(k, i,g)] * mydict_phite[(k, i,g)] for k, i,g in dnode.select('*', '*', g))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the composite keys (k, i, g, t) into separate columns? That way, it is easier for library like Pandas to help you output it into CSV/Excel.

So instead of a dictionary with composite keys

```
data = {
   ('1', '78', 1, 1): 0.10425768417200648,
   ('1', '78', 1, 2): 0.10425768417200648,
   ...
}
```

you should have a list of JSON dictionary instead

```
data = [
   { "k": "1", "i": "78", "g": 1, "t": 1, "value": 0.10425768417200648},
   { "k": "1", "i": "78", "g": 1, "t": 2, "value": 0.10425768417200648},
   ...
]
```

Then, to output as Excel, simply use the code below

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # REPLACE THIS HARDCODED "data" VARIABLE WITH YOUR CODE
    # MAKE SURE THAT "data" IS A LIST OF JSON (PYTHON DICT)
    data = [
        {"k": "1", "i": "78", "g": 1, "t": 1, "value": 0.10425768417200648},
        {"k": "1", "i": "78", "g": 1, "t": 2, "value": 0.10425768417200648},
    ]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```